# Loading two different AJAX requests on two different pages

Tags: wp-query, functions, ajax, jquery, javascript

I hav ebeen trying to call two separate AJAX requests, on separate pages, each pulling in their respective parts. Right now, it only pulls in *ONE* of the AJAX requests on both pages even with specific *IF* page statements that technically should bar them from one another.

AJAX works on both pages it's being called on, however both pages are sharing the *SAME* AJAX call instead of their own separate call despite my efforts.

How can I can front-page.php to just call it's SPECIFIC AJAX call and category.php to just call it's own? Right now I have the code I feel should be doing that but only `cat_loadmore_posts` loads on both pages. I have tried making sure there are no shared function names which makes it all the more curious why it's doing it. I'm interested in finding out how to do this but also the reason behind it. Help is always appreciated.

**front-page.php**

```
<?php
$current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat'            => 5,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged'          => $current_page,
) );

$_SESSION['count'] = 1;
wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
    'ajaxurl'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ),
    'posts'        => json_encode( $the_query->query_vars ),
    'current_page' => $current_page,
    'max_page'     => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>

<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php $count = 0; ?>
        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); get_template_part( 'parts/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php $count++; $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1; ?>

<?php if ($count == 8 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar2') ) : ?>
     <div class="post">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

**category.php**

```
<?php
    $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
    $cat_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'category' => 14, 
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'paged' => $current_page, 
        'order'=>'DESC' 
    ) );

    $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
    wp_localize_script( 'cat_loadmore', 'cat_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ),
        'posts'        => json_encode( $cat_query->query_vars ),
        'current_page' => $current_page,
        'max_page'     => $cat_query->max_num_pages
    ) );        
?>

<div id="catfeed" class="container feed-container">     
<?php if ($cat_query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php while ($cat_query->have_posts()) : $cat_query->the_post(); get_template_part( 'parts/categorycontent', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php $count++; $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

**myloadmore.js - the AJAX call that doesn't work once I added the catloadmore.js - worked previously**

```
jQuery(function($){
    var canBeLoaded = true,
        bottomOffset = 1300; 

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page >= misha_loadmore_params.max_page ) {
            return;
        }
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts,
            'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
        };
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ){
            $.ajax({
                url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function( xhr ){
                    canBeLoaded = false;
                },
                success:function(data){
                    if( data ) {
                        $('#main').find('div.post:last-of-type').after( data );
                        canBeLoaded = true; 
                        misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**catloadmore.js - This one works on category.php AND front-page.php even though I'm not calling it on front-page.php. I just want it to work on category.php**

```
jQuery(function($){
    var canBeLoaded = true, 
    bottomOffset = 1300;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( cat_loadmore_params.current_page >= cat_loadmore_params.max_page ) {     
            return;
        }
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': cat_loadmore_params.posts,
            'page' : cat_loadmore_params.current_page
        };
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ){

            $.ajax({
                url : cat_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function( xhr ){
                    canBeLoaded = false;
                },
                success:function(data){
                    if( data ) {
                        $('#catfeed').find('div.catpost:last-of-type').after( data );
                        canBeLoaded = true;
                        cat_loadmore_params.current_page++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**functions.php**

```
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {
    if ( is_front_page() )
        {
            wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myloadmore.js',
            array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );

function cat_load_more_scripts() {
    if ( is_category() )
        {
            wp_register_script( 'cat_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/catloadmore.js',
            array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'cat_loadmore' );
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cat_load_more_scripts' );


function register_my_session(){
    if( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

add_action('init', 'register_my_session');

function cat_loadmore_ajax_handler() {
    $args = json_decode( wp_unslash( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // load the next page

    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();

            $count = $_SESSION['count'];
            $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1;

            get_template_part( 'parts/categorycontent', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_loadmore', 'cat_loadmore_ajax_handler' );        // Authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'cat_loadmore_ajax_handler' ); // Non-authenticated users

function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler() {
    $args = json_decode( wp_unslash( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // load the next page

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            $count = $_SESSION['count'];
            $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1;

            get_template_part( 'parts/content', get_post_format() );

            <?php if ($count == 8 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar2') ) : ?>
                <div class="series-container post second-series">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('seriesbar2'); ?>

                </div>
            <?php endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' );        // Authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' ); // Non-authenticated users
```

**UPDATED CODE**

**Code after @SallyCJ first answer**
*I left nothing out in the case of oversight on my behalf*

**category.php**

```
<?php
        $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
        $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
        $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
        $change = 0;
        $cat_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5, 
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'offset' => 4, 
            'category__in' => array($cat_id), 
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'paged' => $current_page, 
            'order'=>'DESC' 
    ) );

    $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
    wp_localize_script( 'cat_loadmore', 'cat_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ),
        'posts'        => json_encode( $cat_query->query_vars ),
        'current_page' => $current_page,
        'max_page'     => $cat_query->max_num_pages
    ) );        
?>
    <div id="catfeed" class="container-fluid">
            <?php if ($cat_query->have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php $count = 0; ?>
                <?php while ($cat_query->have_posts()) : $cat_query->the_post(); get_template_part( 'parts/categorycontent', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php 
                    $count++;
                    $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1;
                ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

**functions.php**

```
function cat_load_more_scripts() {
    if ( is_category() )
        {
            wp_register_script( 'cat_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/catloadmore.js',
            array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'cat_loadmore' );
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cat_load_more_scripts' );

add_action('init', 'register_my_session');

function cat_loadmore_ajax_handler() {
    $args = json_decode( wp_unslash( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // load the next page

    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();

            $count = $_SESSION['count'];
            $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1;

            get_template_part( 'parts/categorycontent', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_catloadmore', 'cat_loadmore_ajax_handler' );        // Authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_catloadmore', 'cat_loadmore_ajax_handler' ); // Non-authenticated users

function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler() {
    $args = json_decode( wp_unslash( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // load the next page

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            $count = $_SESSION['count'];
            $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1;

            get_template_part( 'parts/content', get_post_format() );
              if ($count == 4 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar1') ) : ?>
                <div class="series-container post first-series">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('seriesbar1'); ?>

                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($count == 8 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar2') ) : ?>
                <div class="series-container post second-series">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('seriesbar2'); ?>

                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($count == 12 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar3') ) : ?>
                <div class="series-container post third-series">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('seriesbar3'); ?>

                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($count == 16 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar4') ) : ?>
                <div class="series-container post fourth-series">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('seriesbar4'); ?>

                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($count == 20 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar5') ) : ?>
                <div class="series-container post fifth-series">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('seriesbar5'); ?>

                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($count == 24 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar6') ) : ?>
                <div class="series-container post sixth-series">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('seriesbar6'); ?>

                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($count == 28 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar7') ) : ?>
                <div class="series-container post seventh-series">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('seriesbar7'); ?>

                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($count == 32 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar8') ) : ?>
                <div class="series-container post eighth-series">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('seriesbar8'); ?>

                </div>
            <?php endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_myloadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' );        // Authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myloadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' ); // Non-authenticated users
```

**catloadmore.js**

```
jQuery(function($){
var canBeLoaded = true, 
bottomOffset = 1300;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( cat_loadmore_params.current_page >= cat_loadmore_params.max_page ) {     
        return;
    }
    var data = {
        'action': 'catloadmore', // <- same as above action
        'query': cat_loadmore_params.posts,
        'page' : cat_loadmore_params.current_page
    };
    if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ){

        $.ajax({
            url : cat_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function( xhr ){
                canBeLoaded = false;
            },
            success:function(data){
                if( data ) {
                    $('#catfeed').find('div.catpost:last-of-type').after( data );
                    canBeLoaded = true;
                    cat_loadmore_params.current_page++;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

**categorycontent.php - the content being loaded in, truncated for clarity (also just testing this block of code for consistency)**

```
<div class="feed-container row mx-auto align-items-center catpost">  
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid' ) ); ?></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7 mx-auto">
        <h3><a class="align-middle" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </div>
</div><!-- END ROW -->
```

Comment: Have you already checked the answer? Did it help?

Comment: @SallyCJ ironic, I'm actually in the middle of testing the answer right now. I will reply to this within a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm interested in finding out how to do this but also the reason
>   behind it.

I haven't tested your code (the conditional stuff), but from what I could see:

### The Reason

*The AJAX action is the same for both the front page and category AJAX requests:*

1. `myloadmore.js`

   ```
   var data = {
       'action': 'loadmore', // <- same as below action
       'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts,
       'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
   };
   ```
2. `catloadmore.js`

   ```
   var data = {
       'action': 'loadmore', // <- same as above action
       'query': cat_loadmore_params.posts,
       'page' : cat_loadmore_params.current_page
   };
   ```

And in `functions.php`, there are two callbacks (`cat_loadmore_ajax_handler` and `misha_loadmore_ajax_handler`) hooked to the AJAX action named `loadmore`. These callbacks would both be called when an AJAX request was made where the action is `loadmore`, no matter the request came from the front page or a category archive.

But you call `wp_die()` (which is similar to calling `die` or `exit`) from within the callbacks, so once the `cat_loadmore_ajax_handler()` is called, the other callback will not going to run since the script execution has ended. So that's why:

> **catloadmore.js - This one works on category.php AND front-page.php even though I'm not calling it on front-page.php.**

### The "How To" (fix the issue)

*Use different actions:*

1. `myloadmore.js`

   ```
   var data = {
       'action': 'myloadmore',
       ...
   };
   ```
2. `catloadmore.js`

   ```
   var data = {
       'action': 'catloadmore',
       ...
   };
   ```

And in `functions.php`:

1. For the front page:

   ```php
   // AJAX action: myloadmore
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_myloadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' );        // Authenticated users
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myloadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' ); // Non-authenticated users
   ```
2. For category pages:

   ```php
   // AJAX action: catloadmore
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_catloadmore', 'cat_loadmore_ajax_handler' );        // Authenticated users
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_catloadmore', 'cat_loadmore_ajax_handler' ); // Non-authenticated users
   ```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. The front page loads and loads the correct AJAX but now the category doesn't load AJAX at all.I don't see any console errors. Please let me know if I can provide anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the question with your current code? And I just noticed that you're including the sidebar in the AJAX response (`dynamic_sidebar('sidebar');`) - why? Also, there's actually a *syntax error* in the `misha_loadmore_ajax_handler()` - there should be a `?>` after the `get_template_part( 'parts/content', get_post_format() );`.

Comment: I updated the question as requested. The AJAX response dynamic sidebar is a bit complicated but it works for the misha request (long story short, the sidebars interject in posts) for clarity's sake I've included it in the question so you have a full view. It's not necessary for catloadmore so I don't use it there.

Comment: I've tested your code, and after using different `action`s, everything worked fine for me. So try using the exact code in the original question and simply change the `action`s, and see if that helps.

Comment: And note in the/your updated `category.php`, you got the `offset` parameter set to `4` - have you tried removing that? And the `catloadmore.js` file - is it actually loaded (properly) on the page? (try checking the "Sources" tab on Chrome and just locate the file) Check also the `error_log` (PHP error logs) on your site.

Comment: Your suggestion made me realize at some point I must have accidentally deleted my footer php causing JS to not load as it should. Once I solved this and added your changes on `action` it worked perfectly! You're amazing thank you!